# Can't insert a div into another internal div

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help to solve a problem I have.
I have this code:

```
<div id="div1" >
    <div id="edit1">
       hello
       <input type="button" id="b1" onclick="aaa()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use insert into the internal div (id=edit1) another new div I generated.

I tried alike code but it's not running:

```
js:
function aaa()
{
   var elem = createDivLine();
   var el1 = document.getElementById("div1");
   var el2 = el1.getElementById("edit1");
   el2.appendChild(elem);
}

function createDivLine()
{
   var tempDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
   tempDiv1.innerHTML = "Sam";
   return tempDiv1;
}
```

The result should looks like this:

```
<div id="div1" >
    <div id="edit1">
       hello
       <input type="button" id="b1" onclick="createDivTable()"/>
       <div>"Sam"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KknXF/

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not running"?

Comment: You should try jQuery instead. That has very easy implementation for your problem. Go check some tutorials for jQuery.

Comment: Where's the function `createDivTable()` ?

Comment: @techfoobar I think he forgot to change it in the second example.  I'm assuming he meant onclick="aaa()"

Comment: @Harpreet [Have you tried jQuery?](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @Kolink One of the funniest things I've sesen in a long time :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/KknXF/1/ look this

Comment: probably bobince is getting downvotes for not parsing HTML with regexp :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since IDs are unique, it is not valid to attempt to get an element's children by ID.

Remove this line:

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('div1');
```

And change the following line to:

```
var el2 = document.getElementById('edit1');
```

In the event that you have some irrepairably (I can never spell that word...) broken HTML that you can't possibly change, try this:

```
var el2 = document.querySelector("#div1 #edit1");
```

Comment: +1 That's the real problem. However, `.querySelector("#div1 #edit1")` looks awful.

Comment: @VisioN Yeah. I only included it for the sake of covering that situation, just in case there was a reason for trying to get a child by ID. It should of course be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Also HTMLElement just does not have getElementById method.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
function aaa() {
   var elem = createDivLine();
   var el2 = document.getElementById("edit1");
   el2.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UdnuP/1/)